# How can I skip --MORE-- option when I tab in cd?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I wrote in terminal:

```
cd /some_path/
```

then I pressed tab and if there are a lot of directories in some_path I saw a terminal with a lot of lines and at the end there is "--MORE--" option. 
I should press ENTER for a long time to run through this lines. I hate this so my question : can I modify the feature? For example, terminal should print only last n possible cases.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `~/.inputrc` file, you may add

```
set page-completions Off
```

If you do not have such a file, you may simply create it.

This instructs the GNU Readline library (which `bash` uses) to not use the internal pager for completions.

The setting will be active for the *next* `bash` session.

Have a look in the `bash` manual and search for `Readline Variables` to see other variables that may affect the way completions are displayed and/or generated.  All of these variables are to be set in the `~/.inputrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

Just hit 'q' to get back to typing.

Comment: I would call this more of a work-around than a solution...